# How can I redirect viewers who are blocked from social networking to an alternative page

Tags: redirect, iframe, social-networking, facebook-iframe

I've looked at this [Check if Facebook is blocked then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664678/check-if-facebook-is-blocked-then-redirect) to try and help me solve this problem.
I have a web page that has an iframe in that contains my tumblr page. What I want is if someone is at work and social networking is blocked it won't try and load the tumblr in the src of the iframe but load my own page tumblr.htm instead.

so I got this far and realise I don't know what I'm doing really.

```
function isSiteOnline(url,callback) {
// try to load favicon
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    // timeout after 5 seconds
    callback(false);
},5000)

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    callback(true);
}

img.onerror = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    callback(false);
}

img.src = url+"/favicon.ico";
}

isSiteOnline("http://www.tumblr.com",function(found){
if(found) {
    // site is online
window.location.href = 'http://my_page.tumblr.com/';
}
else {
    // site is offline (or favicon not found, or server is too slow)
window.location.href = 'tumblr.htm';
}
}
```

Would this work and what would I put in the src of the iframe tag? would it be src="isSiteOnline" ? and that's where the problem is there are several others on one page (twitter etc.) so I'm fighting a losing battle through lack of experience. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think your approach isn't the best for what you are trying to achieve. Just for viewing tumblr at work/school, you could use a VPN or an SSH tunnel to your home PC or server. But as an answer to your question (how to find out if tumblr is blocked), have you tried contacting the tumblr API or something and load your own tumblr.html when this fails?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what I'm after - I don't want to bypass blocks. What I want to do is detect if the tumblr/facebook/bandcamp etc content is blocked and instead of trying to open the social network content just to simply show my own html page not containing social networking content.

Comment: e.g. the logic being
if favico not returned then show my.html page instead of social network url.

That way when the website IS viewed in work/college it won't have any blocked content it'll show my alternative html pages instead.

I could maybe have an index.html detecting if the social network sites are blocked and redirect to regular homepage or a homepage excluding social media as appropriate.

The main aim of the site is to include social media but rather than hacking content blockers i'd rather just redirect to static html alternatives.