# Change iframe src if current link is down

Tags: html, iframe

I want to make a iframe which will change it's `src=""` if current link in `src=""` is down or other errors.

It will show this if this page is up!

```
<iframe src="http://test1.com"></iframe>
```

If http://test1.com is down it will show http://test2.com

Comment: You can use Javascript

Comment: You will need Javascript  / PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a function run after a timeout which changes the iframes `src`, with an `onload` function of the iframe canceling the timeout.

```
<iframe src="http://test1.tld" id="testIframe" onload="cancelTimeout()"></iframe>
<script>
  var iframeLoadTimeout=window.setTimeout(
    function(){
      document.getElementById("testIframe").src="http://test2.tld";
    },
    10000
  );

  cancelTimeout=function(){
    try {
      window.clearTimeout(iframeLoadTimeout);
    } catch(e) {}
  };
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for the many edits – somehow got carried away in the middle of typing the answer

Comment: will onload be called again, in case even this is down - "http://test2.tld"?

Comment: No, it would not. However, you could of course use `window.setInterval()` instead, which is triggered periodically, and use it to `pop()` URLs off an array, for example. In that case, use `clearInterval()` to cancel it, and have a plan of what to do if all of your URLs fail.

Edit: I would advise against using `setTimeout` recursively, as it just asks for unforeseen troubles down the road.

Answer (score 1):

*JAVASCRIPT*: The first thing you may want to do is check if the site is up or down.

> Just plant an image from the remote site hidden into your site and monitor the load HTTP response status of this image. This might need some tweaks for true cross-browser compatibility. You can see @Spliffster answer to that on this question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814918/2080764)

If it is down you can change the URL of the iframe by doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').src = "http://test2.com";
```