# Javascript How to test if website is live

Tags: javascript

How can i test if a website is Online or Offline ?

Im using the following code and its always returning false. Even if i add a valid ip.

```
var ServerIP = window.localStorage.getItem('serverip');    

if ( ping( ServerIP ) )
{
// Do Stuff
} 

function ping(ip) 
{
    var img = new Image(1,1);
    img.onload = function()
    {
        return true;
    };
    img.onerror = function()
    {
        return false;
    };
    img.src = "http://" + ip + "/pixel.png";
}
```

Comment: `return` in `onerror` and `onload` isn't what you get from `ping(ip)` as they are asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to check if a website is up or not via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814752/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-website-is-up-or-not-via-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return values in your callbacks (onload, onerror) and expect them to be available synchronously as you do here (i.e. when ping is executed):

Most rudimentary way is to use callbacks:

```
ping(ServerIP, function(pingOk) {
  console.log(pingOk);
  if (pingOk) {
    // Do Stuff (note: this happens async)
  }
});

function ping(ip, cb) 
{
    var img = new Image(1,1);
    img.onload = function()
    {
        cb(true);
    };
    img.onerror = function()
    {
        cb(false);
    };
    img.src = "http://" + ip + "/pixel.png";
}
```